# Is $3\mathbb{Z}$ an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is $3\mathbb{Z}$ an integral domain?

My attempt: An integral domain is a commutative ring with an identity $(1 \neq 0)$ with no zero-divisors.
That is $ab = 0 \implies a = 0$ or $b = 0.$

According to the definition, $3\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain because we take $a = 3, b = 6$, but $ab = 18 \neq 0$ where $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$.

Is this true?

Comment: $3\mathbb Z$ is not a ring.

Comment: There is no identity..

Comment: It’s true that $3\Bbb Z$ has no zero divisors, but exhibiting one example does not prove this: you have to show that _whenever_ $a\ne 0$ and $b\ne 0$, then $ab\ne 0$. But you don’t actually need to worry about that: does $3\Bbb Z$ have a multiplicative identity?

Comment: @Todd: That depends on one’s definition. In my terminology $3\Bbb Z$ **is** a ring

Comment: No @BrianM.Scott sir  but  im  confuse  that it can form ring without unity

Comment: Some people require a multiplicative identity element as part of the definition of "ring" and other people don't. But as far as I know, everybody includes it in the definition of "integral domain". So $3\mathbb Z$ is not an integral domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $3 \mathbb{Z}$ has no identity ($1 \notin 3 \mathbb{Z}$, and that is the identity of $\mathbb{Z}$). So it isn't a ring (with identity). That it satifies the other requirements doesn't matter, it must satisfy *all*.

Comment: Be careful - it is possible for a subset $S$ of a ring $R$ to be a ring (with identity) even when $S$ doesn't contain $1_R$. Indeed, this happens whenever $S$ an ideal generated by some nontrivial idempotent in the a ring.

Comment: @Wojowu But it is not possible inside an integral domain.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft True, I'm just pointing out it's not entirely trivial.